# What is the difference of null position placedin front and at back

Tags: java

In java, what is the difference between this 2 lines of code, or the second line of code don't even exist

```
if (name != null){}

if (null != name){}
```

the real code is something like this

```
if ( null != name&& !StringUtils.isEmpty(name) )
```

by the way, I have tested this code and it works

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Difference is in that you cannot assign to NULL anything.

If you would make typo and miss a ! sign within

```
if (name != null) {}
```

You could possibly make

```
if (name = null) {}
```

And by that assign null value to name

Read this

https://knowthecode.io/yoda-conditions-yoda-not-yoda

Comment: so in the general case you just don't need to yoda-order this, but if the type of the thing being assigned is boolean then there is the potential for screwing up (using = where it should be ==) and the yoda-order makes sense. if the answer is edited to clarify then i think it could be good.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between your two top lines of code as both do a valid null check. The main issue is if you did something like this:

```
if (myString.isEmpty() && (myString != null)) {...}
```

This would throw a NullPointerException if myString is null since you're dereferencing the variable before doing the null check. Better to do instead:

```
if ((myString != null) && myString.isEmpty()) {...}
```

The `&&` operator does a boolean AND test, and will short circuit, will end and not do the right sided test if the test on the left is false.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, *!=* is a Logical Operator, and is checking to make sure they are not equivalent, so it doesn't matter which side things are on. For example:

```
String a = "a";

if(a != null)
{
   System.out.println("they are not equal");
}

if(null != a)
{
   System.out.println("they are not equal");
}
```

returns

```
they are not equal
they are not equal
```

Comment: Yeah. They are no difference between both. Thats why i am asking why set the null in front as what we did usually is set the null behind. And the answer i already ticked has solve my puzzle which is u may accidentally set something to null. But if null is set in front u cant set any variable to null. Which will show error if u make a mistake